# Identify Author and whether this X-Men book is canon

Tags: story-identification, marvel, x-men

A few years ago I got an X-Men book by gift in London. It contains a few scenes from the 3rd X-Men movie, and a small comic where Wolverine and Sabretooth fight each other near a gas pump. Logan realizes that Sabretooth also has a dogtag and they talk. They are then surprised by military personnel, who capture them and put them on a plane. Finally, both escape, and Sabretooth kicks Wolverine out of the plane.

Here's the cover.

[image]

So, two questions here. Who is the author of this book? I can't find anything about it on-line. Finally, is this comic inside it canon? Is it original or taken from some other issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comic in your annual is culled and abridged from [X2: X-Men United: The Movie Prequel: Wolverine](http://xmenmovies.wikia.com/wiki/X2:_X-Men_United:_The_Movie_Prequel:_Wolverine) and was written by Brian K. Vaughan with art by Tom Mandrake. **It's 100% canonical with the X-Men films but not with the main comic continuity.**

The remainder of the annual appears to comprise a series of images taken from various canon comics and images from the previous (two) films with text written by an unnamed Panini writer.

Comment: So, if this is canon, and HYDRA appears as villains in the book, doesn't that technically place the X-Men somewhere in MCU continuity?

Comment: @Gothamite24 - Having shared characters doesn't make them part of the same continuity